# Create separate heaps in C

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on a function that does a lot of dynamic memory allocation, however, if this function exceeds a threshold of time, the timer fires. Hence, we need to free all the memory allocated when we started this function.

We use a third party tool to create a heap pool when we enter the function. Hence, any dynamic memory allocation will be from this heap pool.
If the timer fires, we just free this heap pool, and the code continues working with the heap pool before it (it is like a stack of pools).

We need to stop using this third party tool due to cost.

Does any one have a solution idea for this issue to replace this third party tool?

Note: it is not a multi-threaded system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is stack allocation an option? I.e. is that function you\`re developing always executed at the stack top? If yes, then at the timer event you just need to terminate function execution by passing control to its epilogue.

Comment: It would be a lot better if you could show the code for the function.

Comment: This is far too vague to answer. By your description this is a multi-threaded system, so simply have each thread manage it's own allocation and clean-up?

Comment: I think you are just basically searching for a pool allocator. You can find some libraries on [github](https://github.com/silentbicycle/mpool/blob/master/mpool.h).

Answer (score 2):

You can acquire a large memory chunk from heap and write your own allocator and deallocator. And if the timer fire you can free the whole chunk.

Of course this will require a deep-dive into how malloc and free works. And you will need to know how and what information is stored in memory header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer collection where you store all the pointers to the memory you allocate during the function and when the time is over, you go through and free all of them. (You can store any pointer as a void*, so that is possible) This has the advantage that you don't have to code manually your malloc and free. If you want to work more like the tool you were using, you can allocate a big chunk of memory, and then implement your own version of malloc and free that return a pointer to a "free" part of your block. This has the advantage that you now have to do just one free when you leave the function but at the cost of a way more complicated implementation (consider you can run out of memory and have to avoid fragmentation manually). I would suggest you the first approach.

Comment: I think the third party tool uses the first approach; can you elaborate more on how to implement this approach?

Comment: You can use a dynamic list of void*, when you need a malloc, you do it and then you save the pointer in the list. Once the time runs out (or the function ends) you free every saved pointer in the dynamic list. With this solution you can also have a per thread list, giving you the possibility of multi threaded approach with little overhead. To implement the dynamic list I suggest you use a linked list, giving u O(1) insertion, this is because you don't really need access to single pointer, just the whole list. Keep in mind that you can not free memory twice

Comment: If you free the memory during the function, so not all when the time runs out, keep in mind that whatever you free has to be removed from the list of pointer. If you do many deallocation and allocation, don't go with the linked list, because the O(n) search can be very punishing.

Comment: I'm going to do many allocations and deallocations. Thus, what is better than linked list for this situation?

Comment: I would use a set that can be implemented with a [redblack tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). If done this way insertions and deletions are done in O(log(n)) complexity. You can also consider using a [hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), giving you at best O(1) operations. Consider searching for a working implementation though, implementing a collection can be non trivial and many free resources are available that are developed over years of intense testing

Comment: Another good idea could be to return a void** from the allocation and keep using the linked list, so you can free and set to null, given that free(0) is a no-op, that way you have no overhead from the collection while still retaining O(1) allocation. Keep in mind that this solution can not be ideal for you if the number of allocation not completely deleted ends up filling too much memory. You could though periodically clean the linked list from dead nodes